# append action result to modal div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'am trying to append the action result of partial view to a modal popup div on button 
click

Here is the script;

```
Function Edit(ID) {
    debugger

    $('#basicModal1').load('@Url.Action("Edit", "Resource")', "&id=" + codeURIComponent(ID))

  }
```

On button click am calling the function and pass parameter to it.

Modal Popup

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="basicModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">

<div class="modal-dialog" style="margin:90px 0 0 360px">     

        <form style="height:440px;width: 500px;background-color:white" class="form">
        <div class="modal-header popup_back" >

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Edit</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-">
          <fieldset id="EditField" class="account-info" style="margin-top:-20px" >

        </fieldset>

        </div>
             <fieldset class="account-action">

//here i like to place the partial view result 

         </fieldset>
         </form>
        @*<div class="modal-footer">

    </div>*@
```

paritalviewaction is executing but popup is not displaying...

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI for displaying modal popup ?

Answer (score 0):

you should add modal.show event after load event , for example;

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {

    console.log( "Load was performed." );
    // show modal with modal show/hide method

});
```

for your example:

```
$('#basicModal1').load('@Url.Action("Edit", "Resource")', "&id=" + codeURIComponent(ID),
    function(){
        // modal.show
    });
```

Comment: @user3755402, which library are you using for modal?

Comment: No i din use any library, i just created a div called basicModal div